# How to query across generic relations in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, orm, django-rest-framework

I'm making an activities feed but I can't figure out how to avoid N+1 queries.

Basically, a Team or Place have followers/activities, each user is a follower that has an activities feed pulled from the teams/places they follow.

Snippets from my models:

```
class Follower(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class Activity(models.Model):
    ...
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class Team(models.Model):
    ...
    followers = GenericRelation('Follower')
    activities = GenericRelation('Activity')

class Place(models.Model):
    ...
    followers = GenericRelation('Follower')
    activities = GenericRelation('Activity')
```

I'm using DRF and have a basic serializer for Activity, I think the tricky part is inside the view:

```
 class ActivityViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

     def list(self, request):
         #N+1 query
         activities = [f.content_object.activities.all() for f in request.user.follower_set.all()]

         ...
```

So this works, but is there a better way to do that query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def list(self, request):
    items = {}
    for f in request.user.follower_set.all():
        items.setdefault(f.content_type_id, []).append(f.object_id)
    activities = Activity.objects.get_empty_queryset() # get_empty_query_set in <1.5
    for k, v in items.iteritems():
        activities |= Activity.objects.filter(content_type=k, object_id__in=v)
```

This boils down to 2 queries. It makes use of the fact that if a `Follower` and an `Activity` are related to the same object (team or place), the `content_type` and `object_id` are the same. A little python processing, and tada, you have all activities related to the current user in 2 queries.

Comment: Ah thanks, this is really clever, unfortunately I don't just have team/places. So this would have still have a number of queries based on how many generic objects are related, Although that # will most likely be less than the number of things being followed, so this will be an improvement. Do you think it's possible to write a raw SQL query here?

Comment: Note that by using `|` on a queryset, the filters get merged and it executes as a single query. That's one query for followers (`for f in request.user.follower_set.all()`) and one query for activities, so 2 queries in total, regardless of the number of related models. Only if you were to actually fetch the related objects, would you need another query for each model.